# How to catch all the errors happening during the execution of an SQL file containing multiple INSERT INTO statements to insert multiple rows?

Tags: oracle, insert, error-handling

I've got a sql file TW_popul.sql containing multiple INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO conversion_fee (FEE_ID, FEE_AMOUNT, DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, FEE_TYPE, PAYMENT_ORDER_ID) 
VALUES (32353357, 8.67, 0, 'com.transferwise.fx.payment.fee.RequestFee', 29639547);

INSERT INTO conversion_fee (FEE_ID, FEE_AMOUNT, DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, FEE_TYPE, PAYMENT_ORDER_ID) 
VALUES (32358776, 1.84, 0, 'com.transferwise.fx.payment.fee.RequestFee', 29643922);

INSERT INTO conversion_fee (FEE_ID, FEE_AMOUNT, DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, FEE_TYPE, PAYMENT_ORDER_ID) 
VALUES (32374786, 11.26, 0, 'com.transferwise.fx.payment.fee.RequestFee', 29656743);

INSERT INTO conversion_fee (FEE_ID, FEE_AMOUNT, DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, FEE_TYPE, PAYMENT_ORDER_ID) 
VALUES (32374911, 1.49, 0, 'com.transferwise.fx.payment.fee.RequestFee', 29656849);
```

Some of those insert statements a breaking constraint rules and throwing errors(ex. "ERROR at line 1: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TW.BT_BANK_TRANSACTION_ID_PK) violated" ).

```
1 row created.


1 row created.


1 row created.

INSERT INTO conversion_fee (FEE_ID, FEE_AMOUNT, DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, FEE_TYPE, PAYMENT_ORDER_ID)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (TW.CF_FEE_ID_PK) violated



1 row created.


1 row created.
```

How do I collect all the rows generating an error (in an Error_table for example)?

I've read about TRY... CATCH but i'm not sure it applies to catching multiple errors.

Comment: The error message you posted suggests you are using Oracle and not SQL Server. I suggest you change the tags for the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[Inserting Data with DML Error Logging](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-B71385AD-2D21-42F3-9249-3D6364887746)

Example:

```
begin
  DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG(dml_table_name => 'conversion_fee');
end;
/
```

This creates a table called `err$_conversion_fee` that can collect the errors for table `conversion_fee` if specified in the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO conversion_fee (FEE_ID, FEE_AMOUNT, DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, FEE_TYPE, PAYMENT_ORDER_ID) 
VALUES (32353357, 8.67, 0, 'com.transferwise.fx.payment.fee.RequestFee', 29639547)
LOG ERRORS INTO err$_conversion_fee ('daily_load') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better approach would be to verify if the record already exists and would violate the constraint, and only then try to insert it. You would have to script a bit around this file.

Another possibility is to insert everything to a **temp table** first, and then do the insert to table `conversion_fee` in batch, selectively with a WHERE/IN/EXISTS clause, rather than on a row by row basis. 
The temp table should simply be a copy of `conversion_fee`, without data and the constraints.

Then it should not be too difficult to idenfity the duplicate rows, for example by doing a JOIN between `conversion_fee` and the temp table.

With a text editor, you can easily replace the table name in your source file to something else (the name of a temp table). Import your file to that temp table, and then compare with `conversion_fee`.

I can't provide full code right now, since the table structure is not known, nor is the constraint. But this is an idea.